# Как добиться отображения функции модели в django-tables2

Tags: django

*версия django 3*

Добрый день, я новичок в django
Уже как сутки не могу найти ответ на такой вопрос: как вывести функцию из модели в django_tables_2

```
   #my model
class Sovet(models.Model):
    sovet_title = models.CharField('sovet', max_length=50)
    sovet_date = models.DateField('data')

    #**Вот эту функцию пытаюсь отобразить**
    def count_assignment(self):
        companies_qty = Assignment.objects.filter(sovet=self)
        return companies_qty.count()


#my table
class SovetTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Sovet
        sequence = ('sovet_title','sovet_date') 
        exclude = ("id",)   
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap4.html"


#my view
def PersonListView(request):
    table = SovetTable(Sovet.objects.all())
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render(request, 'sovet/list_djt.html', {'table': table})
```

В итоге у меня получилось вывести таблицу с полями **sovet  |  data**

Пытаюсь добиться вывода: **sovet |  data  |  count_assignment**

Answer (score 0):

Нашел ответ, все делается через tables.Column(). При первоначальном чтении манула использовал переводчик... не понял, прочитав на языке оригинала (кое как) понял что надо сделать:

```
#my table
class SovetTable(tables.Table):
    ##Вот это добавил#####
    count_assignment = tables.Column()
    ######################
    class Meta:
        model = Sovet
        sequence = ('sovet_title','sovet_date') 
        exclude = ("id",)   
        template_name = "django_tables2/bootstrap4.html"
```

*Только до конца не понял какие параметры в Column( параметры ) можно передавать, буду изучать*